# What punctuation do I use in "stage performers, their stage: the sky"?

Tags: punctuation

I have a sentence which currently looks like

> They dance in the distance like graceful stage performers, their stage: the sky!

The comma introduces more detail, but the colon is "more" than a comma and should ideally be "less".

What punctuation should I use between

1. *performers* and *their*
2. *stage* and *the sky*?

Comment: I've made rather a large edit and the title could still be better. Hopefully I've expressed what you see as the problem.

Comment: Commenters: please write an answer. Even if the sentence is fine, explain *why* it's fine. Your answers will help other askers (especially if this question can be a duplicate target).

Comment: No changes needed -- the punctuation in your example is fine as it is.

Comment: Personally I think the colon adds drama, no need to change it.

Comment: Don't repeat the word stage. That wrecks the sentence!

Answer (score 18):

I'd agree that it would be a good style choice to have [medium pause/break] ... [short pause/break] here. One way round this is to push the supercomma usage of the semicolon:

- *They dance in the distance like graceful stage performers; their stage, the sky!*

Hopefully, the rather poetic register will dissuade hyperprescriptivists from claiming foul. But here are several examples of the use of a comma to replace omitted words that goes beyond that of the usual gapping comma (standing in for words already used in the sentence: *John likes strawberry ice cream; Sue, vanilla*). Fragments are usually left:

> - Not five blocks further, in the northern direction, a man stood on the corner, grimly silent, both hands in the pockets of his shabby top
>   coat, disappointment stamped on his countenance. His only plea, the
>   finding of a job. His was gone, but his family had to eat ....

[[The Reflector; 1933](http://www2.vcdh.virginia.edu/saxon/servlet/SaxonServlet?source=/xml_docs/rp_news/raceplace_news.xml&style=/xml_docs/rp_news/raceplace_news.xsl&level=single&order=none&item=va.np.reflector.12.02.33)]

> - *Tomorrow, the World!* is a 1944 black-and-white film directed by Leslie Fenton ....

> - But for Mark Standish, 'Run through the Jungle' has a totally different meaning as he literally runs through the Vietnam jungle to
>   get away from his decisions. His sole purpose, to destroy the one
>   person he sees as the root of all his bad decisions.

[[Natalia Morrow](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Run-Through-Jungle-Morrow-Family/dp/1393104541)]

> - ... or the [Holy] Ghost ... will ... bid us turn
>
> and flame unto a last consuming light:
>
> His light, our light ....

[[Scott Cairns, poet](https://alexjoyner.com/2018/10/10/burning-from-beginning-to-end-with-scott-cairns/)]

> - Black Lives Matter ... You bleed, we bleed. You suffer, we suffer.

[[Waves of Positivity](https://www.facebook.com/wavesofpositivityofficial/videos/black-lives-matter-sign-the-petition-in-my-bio-you-bleed-we-bleed-you-suffer-we-/2617808648470845/?locale=zh_CN)]

And [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mi_casa,_su_casa) and [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mi+casa%2C+su+casa) accept

> - mi casa, su casa

as having entered the lexicon.
The literary (or pseudo-literary in the last example?) flavour is seen in these examples.

One reference not confining the 'omitted words comma' to gapping is:

> 1.13 Consider using a comma where one or more words are omitted but understood in context.
>
> - (a) Understood words. A comma pause signals the reader that an obvious word or phrase, commonly the verb from the previous clause, is
>   to be understood at this point.

[[Redbook; Garner, I believe](https://turtletalk.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/redbook-comma-rules.pdf)]

If you want to play it safe, signal a slightly more marked first pause with a dash:

- *They dance in the distance like graceful stage performers – their stage, the sky!*

(To my mind, the spaced en-dash common in the UK is less jarring. And the colon is becoming dated in running text.)

An ellipsis gives even more pause for reflection.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152047/discussion-on-answer-by-edwin-ashworth-what-punctuation-do-i-use-in-stage-perfo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

*Their stage the sky* is an absolute phrase. An absolute phrase has its own noun or pronoun along with a participle phrase. When the participle is a form of *to be*, it can be omitted (which is what’s happening in your absolute phrase):

> *They dance in the distance like graceful stage performers, **their stage [being] the sky**.*
>
> *They dance in the distance like graceful stage performers, **their stage the sky**.*

No punctuation is needed in your absolute phrase.

Here’s an example from *ThoughtCo*’s [What Are Absolute Phrases in English?](https://www.thoughtco.com/absolute-phrase-grammar-1689049):

> *The storks circled high above us, **their slender bodies sleek and black against the orange sky**.*

And another from *Guide to Grammar and Writing*’s [The Garden of Phrases](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/phrases.htm#absolute):

> ***The season [being] over**, they were mobbed by fans in Times Square.*

Comment: Oh dear, Tinfoil Hat! An absolute is not a phrase but a non-finite clause., so the term is not relevant here. "Their stage: the sky" is a supplementary NP with "their stage "as head and "the sky" as an elaboration of the head, marked by the elaborative marker, i.e. a colon. Simples!

Comment: @BillJ — Perhaps according to your grammar of choice. But an absolute phrase it is in traditional grammar terms.

Comment: Please see here [link](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/absolute-clause) and here [link](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780192800879.001.0001/acref-9780192800879-e-8)

Comment: A broader usage is given in the [New World Encylopedia](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Adjective#:~:text=Absolute%20adjectives%20do%20not%20belong,look%20where%20he%20was%20going.%22) (my earlier reference was the University of Sheffield: User-defined Dictionary (Beta)): 'Absolute adjectives do not belong to a larger construction (aside from a larger adjective phrase), and typically modify either the subject of a sentence or whatever noun or pronoun they are closest to; for example, happy is an absolute adjective in "The boy, happy with his lolly, did not look where he was going."'

Comment: @BillJ — I'm not sure what you’re trying to show with your links — that some people call it an absolute clause? Others call it an absolute phrase. [“See here link.”](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780190491482.001.0001/acref-9780190491482-e-47)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't why you cite the term 'absolute adjectives', which are simply adjectives that are non-gradable. We are discussing here adjective phrase vs absolute clause. In your example, "happy" is gradable: "The boy, very/slightly happy with his lolly, ...". Moreover, the AdjP "happy with his lolly" is best analysed as a  'predicative adjunct, cf. the PC "The boy was (very) happy with his lolly".

Comment: @TinfoilHat Your link refers to modifiers. The whole point of the term 'absolute' is that it is not a modifier but a supplement, as in "[His face contorted with pain], he screamed out for help".

Comment: There is a discussion of the three distinct definitions (distributional as in the example above; contrasting with comparative and superlative; and as one of the three subsets of 'ungradable' along with 'extreme' and 'classifying') of 'absolute adjectives' in use. CGEL is not the final arbiter of metalanguage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Who said anything about CGEL? This is plain common sense. I think you're confusing 'grade' and 'gradable.' Grade is the system of contrasts between plain, comparative and superlative, while gradable denotes a property that can apply in varying degrees; for example gradable adjectives are those that take degree modifiers like "very", "rather", slightly" and the like, as in your "lolly" example. Absolute adjectives are those that are not gradable.

Comment: 'big     bigger     biggest
   
The lowest point on the scale is known as the ABSOLUTE form, the middle point is known as the COMPARATIVE form, and the highest point is known as the SUPERLATIVE form.' [[UCL](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/compare.htm)] // An overview of the variously defined term is at [Alphadictionary.com](https://www.alphadictionary.com/blog/?p=172) (with references). This is a descriptive, not arrogative, analysis of usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To call the base form of an adjective an 'absolute' makes no sense. The term 'absolute' is normally used for adjectives that are not gradable, like "perfect" "impossible" and "supreme". The base (your 'lowest') form is called the plain form, so the contrast is between plain, comparative and superlative. In contemporary grammar, that is!

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted a slightly different intonation:

> They dance in the distance like graceful stage performers. Their stage? The sky!

But the alliteration of "dance in the distance" makes me want another alliteration to balance it, perhaps:

> They dance in the distance like lithe stage performers. Their stage? The sky!

Comment: Not sure how changing _graceful_ to _lithe_ makes it an alliteration?

Comment: @user405662 "like lithe" Or is alliteration the wrong term for that in that place?

Comment: It is. I overlooked it  for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

like graceful stage performers, their stage: the sky! is poor due to **the repetition of stage**.

- They dance in the distance like graceful performers, their stage: the sky!

**There is no need to repeat stage**. And you can make more impact by not using: their stage is the sky.

- They dance in the distance, graceful performers, their stage: the sky!

Even better for impact. With two ellipses.

Comment: The question doesn't ask to improve the *style*.  There are a dozen ways of rewriting the sentence. The OP wants to know about the *punctuation*. P.S The phrase "stage actors" and "stage" are quite different in meaning and form and are not examples of poor writing style. Removing "stage performers" you are in fact modifying the meaning of the original sentence but that's "opinable" (which my spellchecker tells me is incorrect but it's listed in dictionaries, and its shorter than saying "that's a question of opinion")

Comment: I quite like the fact that "stage" is used twice in the sentence, it juxtaposes the manmade stage with the one created by nature.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Fyi, I always improve them when the question hinges on something like this.  I think non-repetition is better. I never said that state actors is poor writing. It is the unneeded repetition that is. If you say"their stage, the sky", you are not changing the meaning of performers without the word stage at all. Recently, we've had questions re grammar from bad translations and one even created a very funny crash blossom. Here it is just bad style.